# Error when transferring Docker Image to Docker Hub using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, dockerhub

Below is a portion of a Jenkins Pipeline Script that I am using to build a Docker Image and Deploy it to the Docker Hub. The problem that I am having is that after executing the Pipeline, the Docker Image is not transferred to Docker Hub ~and~ the local Docker Image (created during the process) is not erased.

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    registry = "<my_docker_hub userid>/object"
    registryCredential = 'dockerhub'
  }
  agent { label 'ubuntu16.04-slave-two' }
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
        steps {
            ...
            }
    }
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
            sh "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -p $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER build "
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy Image') {
      steps{
        sh "docker push $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
      }
    }
    stage('Remove Unused docker image') {
      steps{
        sh "docker rmi $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even though **I get a SUCCESS message when building the image**:

```
   Successfully built fe86784636c2
   Successfully tagged <docker_hub_id>object44_website:latest
```

The image is not transferred over to the Docker Hub.

Below is the log I got when running the Pipeline code:

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on ubuntu16.04-slave-two in /var/jenkins/workspace/oracle-client-with-flask
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Cloning Git)

[... snip ...']

Building authorize-service
Step 1/11 : FROM oraclelinux:7
 ---> a803b2474b20

[... snip ...]

Step 3/4 : COPY . /var/www/html/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e0b4cd5713c0
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe86784636c2
Successfully built fe86784636c2
Successfully tagged <docker_hub_id>object44_website:latest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Image)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push <docker_hub_id>/object:44
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/<docker_hub_id>/object]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: <docker_hub_id>/object
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Remove Unused docker image)
Stage "Remove Unused docker image" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I get the Image successfully to the Docker Hub?

TIA

**EDIT: Here is the docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3'

services:
  authorize-service:
    build: ./authorizations
    container_name: authorize-service
    environment:
      - DB_IP=XXX.XX.XX.XX
      - DB_PORT=1521
      - DB_SID=TEST
      - DB_USER=xxxxxxx
      - DB_PASS=xxxxxxx
    ports:
      - 2700:5000
    networks:
      - kdcnetwork
  testtab-service:
    build: ./testtab
    container_name: testtab-service
    environment:
      - DB_IP=XXX.XX.XX.XX
      - DB_PORT=1521
      - DB_SID=TEST
      - DB_USER=xxxxx
      - DB_PASS=xxxxx
    ports:
      - 2800:5000
    networks:
      - kdcnetwork 
  website:
    build: ./website
    container_name: testtab-website
    links:
      - testtab-service 
    volumes:
      - ./website:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    networks: 
      - kdcnetwork 
    depends_on:
      - testtab-service

networks:
  kdcnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide docker-compose file so I cannot give very accurate answer but I can simply find that

`Successfully tagged <docker_hub_id>object44_website:latest`

differs from what you are trying to push:

`docker push <docker_hub_id>/object:44`

those 2 names must be the same.

Edit:

So you must change section in your docker-compose to following

```
website:
    build: ./website
    image: <docker_hub_id>/object:44
```

so docker-compose will build image `<docker_hub_id>/object:44` and your docker push command should be able to push it

Comment: Thanks for the response!  You said: "You didn't provide docker-compose" - I have added it now. What should I do?

Comment: P.S. I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer if it works for you :)

Comment: again, thanks for your input - and - of course I will accept your answer. I just have one question about it. Is it possible to do what you are saying from the command line (in other words, is it possible to do what you are saying using "docker-compose") Would one tag the image from the docker-compose.yml file only?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not possible to do using docker-compose command. You should rather consider to change build to use command `docker build -t <docker_hub_id>/object:44  ./website `